# How do I install opencv on my Raspberry Pi 4 properly?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

I kept getting this error.

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
```

I've checked the python and opencv installed on my raspberry pi and I think they are compatible. I don't know what's wrong because I tried many ways to resolve this already. Anybody can help?

Python 3.9.2, opencv 4.5.1

My code:

```py
import cv2 

print cv2. __version__
```

Comment: could add the command that raised the error? what is the result of `$ python -m pip list | grep "cv"`?

Comment: https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: the command that i used is:

import cv2 
print cv2. __version__